# Использование #pragma comment

Tags: c, c++

Для чего используется?

```
 #pragma comment
```

Answer (score 17):

Пожалуй стоит привести примеры:

```
// автоматически залинкует libname.lib
#pragma comment( lib, "libname.lib" )

// автоматически залинкует emapi.lib
#pragma comment( lib, "emapi" )

// при вызове линкера будет использован дополнительный параметр /include:__mySymbol
#pragma comment( linker, "/include:__mySymbol" )

// Строка "Compiled on ДАТА-КОМПИЛЯЦИИ at ВРЕМЯ-КОМПИЛЯЦИИ" будет записана в ЕХЕ файл
// ни на что влиять не будет, но будет видна в ЕХЕшнике в виде текста.
#pragma comment( user, "Compiled on " __DATE__ " at " __TIME__ )

// То же самое
#pragma comment( user, "Ваша строка, просто будет болтаться в EXE файле" )

// В ЕХЕшник будет записано имя и версия компилятора. Ни на что не влияет
// но можно будет потом посмотреть.
#pragma comment( compiler )
```

MSDN также говорит, что

```
 #pragma( exestr, "ваш комментарий" )
```

устаревшая и в будущих версиях компилятора поддерживаться не будет.

Вместо нее можно использовать:

```
#pragma( user, "ваша строка коммента" )
```

Answer (score 2):

Для [Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7(v=VS.100).aspx) помещает:

- версию компилятора (compiler),
- строку (exestr),
- библиотеку для поиска (lib),
- опцию для сборщика (linker),
- произвольный комментарий (user)

в объектный файл.

Answer (score -1):

Следует обратить внимание, что

```
#pragma comment
```

"фишка" исключительно Microsoft'овского компилятор. GCC так не умеет. За что ему и спасибо.